# How do i use zustand to make a copy of an object in state?

Tags: react-native, zustand

When I login a user in firestore, I want to create a user object in state that persists through the app. My zustand store looks like:

```
const userStore = create(set => ({
user:{
    uid:"",
    name:"",
    phone:"",
    email:"",
    city:"",
    state:"",
    friends:"",
    firstLogin:1,
    likes:{},
},
```

I return a copy of the user object from firebase once with all of the above features. How do I transfer them to the store? My best guess was:

```
setUser: () =>
    set((state) => ({
    user: 
      {
        uid:state.uid,
        name:state.name,
        phone:state.phone,
        email:state.email,
        city:state.city,
        state:state.state,
        friends:state.friends,
        firstLogin:state.firstLogin,
        likes:state.likes,
      }})),
```

But this feels wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the state, you could proceed as follow:

```
const shallowCopy = {...useStore.getState()}
```

with `useStore` being the store previously created.

Example with just a slice of your state

```
const sliceShallowCopy = {...useStore.getState().comments}
```

You just get state and create a shallow copy by destructuring it.

In your case, it seems to me that you just want to set user state according to your data from firebase.

I would do something like:

```
function setUser(userData) {
    userStore.setState(() => ({ user: {...userData})
}
```

This is referred as a practice with 'no store actions' [zustand doc](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/practice-with-no-store-actions)